# Select data between two dates exclude some days

Tags: mysql, date

I need to make query that selects data between two dates but exclude weekdays and some other days that are for example public holidays.

```
SELECT 
`tblproduction`.`OperaterID`, `tblproduction`.`OperationID`, 
SUM(`tblproduction`.`TotalProduced`) AS TotalProduced, 
SUM(`tblproduction`.`TotalProducedOperator`) AS TotalProducedOp,
'Normal working day' AS DayType
FROM `tblproduction` 
WHERE tblproduction.StartDateTime >= '2015-02-01 00:00:00' AND (tblproduction.StartDateTime <= '2015-02-28 23:59:59') AND tblproduction.OperaterID = 10
AND (DAYOFWEEK(tblproduction.StartDateTime) IN (1,7)) AND (DATE(tblproduction.StartDateTime) NOT IN (SELECT HolidayDate FROM tblholidays))
GROUP BY `tblproduction`.`OperaterID`, `tblproduction`.`OperationID`
UNION ALL
SELECT 
`tblproduction`.`OperaterID`, `tblproduction`.`OperationID`, 
SUM(`tblproduction`.`TotalProduced`) AS TotalProduced, 
SUM(`tblproduction`.`TotalProducedOperator`) AS TotalProducedOp,
'Weekend' AS DayType
FROM `tblproduction` 
WHERE tblproduction.StartDateTime >= '2015-02-01 00:00:00' AND (tblproduction.StartDateTime <= '2015-02-28 23:59:59') AND tblproduction.OperaterID = 10
AND (DAYOFWEEK(tblproduction.StartDateTime) NOT IN (1,7)) AND (DATE(tblproduction.StartDateTime) NOT IN (SELECT HolidayDate FROM tblholidays))
GROUP BY `tblproduction`.`OperaterID`, `tblproduction`.`OperationID`
```

For that purpose i have table with predefined dates that represents public holidays named tblHolidays. One of criteria in sql query is avoid counting pieces made during the holiday date. By running this query is steel includes those dates that are holidays. What should I change in query?

Comment: I would extend you public holiday table to have all dates (for the past/next few years) with a column that indicates what kind of day it is. Then your query would be a simple join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe start with this...

```
SELECT p.OperaterID
     , p.OperationID
     , SUM(p.TotalProduced) TotalProduced
     , SUM(p.TotalProducedOperator) TotalProducedOp
     , CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(p.startdatetime) IN (1,7) THEN 'Normal working day' ELSE 'Weekend' END DayType
  FROM tblproduction p
 WHERE p.StartDateTime >= '2015-02-01 00:00:00' AND p.StartDateTime <= '2015-02-28 23:59:59'
   AND p.OperaterID = 10
   AND DATE(p.StartDateTime) NOT IN (SELECT HolidayDate FROM tblholidays)
 GROUP 
    BY p.OperaterID
     , p.OperationID
     , CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(p.startdatetime) IN (1,7) THEN 'Normal working day' ELSE 'Weekend' END
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same result. Quntities that are produced in dates which are defined as holidays are also calculated.

Comment: It gives the same result, but in half as much query, so it's still a better place to start from.