# Get values between now and now + 5days in php mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch all the values between followupdate = now and followupdate = now + 5days. Currently I'm using this query which is not returning today's values though it is returning the next 5 days values

```
SELECT * FROM leads WHERE followupdate >= NOW() AND followupdate <= NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

Comment: DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select data between two dates exclude some days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852039/select-data-between-two-dates-exclude-some-days)

Comment: `WHERE followupdate >= NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)`

Comment: @Cruzer this is skipping my today's rows

Comment: @ShujaatShaikh, then you should use CURDATE() instead NOW()

Comment: If any the provided solution was helpful, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM leads WHERE followupdate >= DATE(NOW()) AND followupdate <= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

As `NOW` returns the entire timestamp use `DATE()` to get today's date.

Comment: Can you tell me why my query skips today's rows?

Comment: It is because `NOW()` returns the entire timestamp like `2017-11-30 11:38:23`. But you only need date like `2017-11-30` and that is why your query skips today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) to get today's date, then add 5 to it.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    leads 
WHERE 
    followupdate >= CURDATE() AND followupdate <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```